# $.getJSON, Call back doesn't run

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

#### The Problem: The call back on my $.getJSON request doesn't run.

On page load, nothing is logged to the console or updated on the page, but when the function is pasted in to the console it executes correctly.

jQuery:

```
 $(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log("callback running");
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(jqXHR);
      $('#region-name').html(location.region_name);
    });
 });
  console.log(typeof $ !== "undefined" && $ !== null);

  console.log($.getJSON != null);
```

Both of the console logs after the function log true.

The above version is reduced for SO. Here is the full script.

```
#Geo.Coffee
$ ->
    $.getJSON(
        'http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?',
        (location, textStatus, jqXHR) ->  # example where I update content on the page.
            console.log "callback running"
            console.log textStatus
            console.log jqXHR  
            $('#region-name').html location.region_name  
            $('#areacode').html location.areacode
            $('#ip').html location.ip  
            $('#zipcode').html location.zipcode  
            $('#longitude').html location.longitude  
            $('#latitude').html location.latitude 
            $('#country-name').html location.country_name  
            $('#country-code').html location.country_code
            $('#city').html location.city 
            $('#region-code').html location.region_code
            $('container main content').append "<p>#{location.country_code}</p>"
            localStorage['loc'] = location.country_code
            if localStorage.loc is "US" then alert "Your From The US."  
    )#.fail(-> alert "fail").done( (loc) -> alert "done")
    console.log localStorage.loc
console.log $?
console.log $.getJSON?
```

compiled js:

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(location, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log("callback running");
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(jqXHR);
      $('#region-name').html(location.region_name);
      $('#areacode').html(location.areacode);
      $('#ip').html(location.ip);
      $('#zipcode').html(location.zipcode);
      $('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
      $('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
      $('#country-name').html(location.country_name);
      $('#country-code').html(location.country_code);
      $('#city').html(location.city);
      $('#region-code').html(location.region_code);
      localStorage['loc'] = location.country_code;
      if (localStorage.loc === "US") {
        return alert("Your From The US.");
      }
    });
    return console.log(localStorage.loc);
  });

  console.log(typeof $ !== "undefined" && $ !== null);

  console.log($.getJSON != null);

}).call(this);
```

html:

```
<p id="region-name"></p>
<p id="areacode"></p>
<p id="ip"></p>
<p id="zipcode"></p>
<p id="longitude"></p>
<p id="latitude"></p>
<p id="country-name"></p>
<p id="country-code"></p>
<p id="city"></p>
<p id="region-code"></p>
```

correct fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5DjEq/1/

Comment: can you show us fiddle?

Comment: Your jsFiddle works for me

Comment: not familiar with coffeescript... I'm getting an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: textStatus is not defined` http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fAt77/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny added the compiled js.

Comment: not sure that is the compiled js because `location` in the callback is refering the window.location see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fAt77/2/

Comment: what do you mean? like  (location, textStatus, jqXHR)? the indentation should be like this btw http://jsfiddle.net/fAt77/3/

Comment: crazy!!! see this http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fAt77/4/ - it is working - but not http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fAt77/4/

Comment: I think the problem is with indentation see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fAt77/5/

Comment: @ArunPJohny works in both for me? could the site be that unreliable?

Comment: @ArunPJohny works in that fiddle for me was well

Comment: so the problem is solved now right

Comment: well not really, it still doesnt work on my site and its strange that it works for me and not for you. We didn't actually change anything.  We jus added Jason.  Something  else must be going on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44745/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-agconti)

Answer (score 4):

Your element id is the problem remove the `#`

```
<p id="region-name"></p>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S9FXZ/)

Or escape the id selector like `$('#\\#region-name').html(location.region_name);` - demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S9FXZ/2/)

---

Also since the remote resource supports jsonp I would recommend using it if you want to support IE <= 8 - now you are using CORS support provided by the remote resource

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function (location, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("callback running");
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
        $('#region-name').html(location.region_name);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CpRL4/)

---

Looks like your coffeescript has a indentation problem

```
$ ->
$.getJSON(
          'http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?',
          (location, textStatus, jqXHR) ->  # example where I update content on the page.
              console.log "callback running"
              console.log textStatus
              console.log jqXHR  
              $('#region-name').html location.region_name  
              $('#areacode').html location.areacode
              $('#ip').html location.ip  
              $('#zipcode').html location.zipcode  
              $('#longitude').html location.longitude  
              $('#latitude').html location.latitude 
              $('#country-name').html location.country_name  
              $('#country-code').html location.country_code
              $('#city').html location.city 
              $('#region-code').html location.region_code
              $('container main content').append "<p>#{location.country_code}</p>"
              localStorage['loc'] = location.country_code
              if localStorage.loc is "US" then alert "Your From The US."  
          )#.fail(-> alert "fail").done( (loc) -> alert "done")
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fAt77/)

Comment: adding `?callback=?` doesnt solve my issue. Also if you remove it in your fiddle it still works.  Why would adding jsonp be necessary?

Comment: thats a problem with the fiddle but not the actual problem. see my question update

Comment: @agconti Given that's all we've got to go on and this answer works, I'd say it **is** the actual problem

Comment: @agconti that is the problem you have given us... we can only go with what you have given us

Comment: I added a fiddle at one of Dalorzo's request, but made an error. Sorry the fiddle didn't fully represent my problem.

Comment: Correct answer, but for some reason it doesn't work on my site, any idea on how to test for what else it could be. +1 for the jsonp suggestion.

Comment: Sorry indendation is wrong in the fiddle, but correct in the question.

Answer (score 2):

you need to make jsonp request

`$.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?',`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turned out to be my addblocker. uBlock Origin blocked several ip services. After disabling it, everything worked fine.